# Undefined variable: query

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I'm attempting to make a login system with Codeigniter and it's giving me this error message and I can not seem to find any solution:

Message: Undefined variable: query

Filename: controllers/login.php

Line Number: 18

This is my Controller:

```
<?php
     class Login extends CI_Controller {
     function index()
        {
        $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
         $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
        }


       function validate_credentials() 
      {
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $this->membership_model->validate();

if($query) 
{
    $data = array(
     'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
     'is_logged_in' => true
        );

    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    redirect('site/members_area');

}
        else 
     {
    $this->index();
    }
}
}
```

This is my Model:

```
 <?php
        Class Membership_model extends CI_Model {

        function validate()

        {
            $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
            $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
            $query = $this->db->get('membership');

            if($query->num_rows == 1) 
        {
                return true;
        }

        }
            }
?>
```

And This is the view:

```
<div id="login_form">
 <h1>Login, fool!</h1>
 <?php 
    echo form_open('login/validate_credentials');
    echo form_input('username', 'Username');
    echo form_input('password', 'Password');
    echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');
    echo anchor('login/signup', 'Create Account');
 ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please format your code when asking a question

Comment: The Format to Display a Question is not good please try to edit the code and retry again such  you are able to get Response Quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

`$query = $this->membership_model->validate();`

Answer (score 0):

The $query variable is not present in Controller's Method. You should use

```
$query =  $this->membership_model->validate();
```

It will send Boolean status of Validation.